# electron and react with expressjs build issues

Tags: reactjs, express, npm, electron

I have an app almost ready to package, I've been using express, react, bootstrap and electron. I can run the app file using npm start, But i cant package it. Build completes and when i run application file electron open but neither react runs on localhost nor express.

My directory structure is as follows

```
     - api
       - containes expressjs (package.json)
     - client
       - containes react and electron (package.json)
```

*let me know if you need more detailed structure

This is my procfile

```
    react: npm run react-start
    electron: npm run electron-start
    express: npm start --prefix ../api/
```

This is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "POSifier",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "description": "system",
      "private": true,
      "homepage": "../",
      "dependencies": {
        "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
        "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "@wojtekmaj/react-datetimerange-picker": "^3.0.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
        "canvasjs": "^1.8.3",
        "custom-electron-titlebar": "^3.2.5",
        "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "jsbarcode": "^3.11.3",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
        "pouchdb": "^7.2.2",
        "pouchdb-authentication": "^1.1.3",
        "pouchdb-browser": "^7.2.2",
        "pouchdb-find": "^7.2.2",
        "pouchdb-react-native": "^6.4.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
        "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^5.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-fade-in": "^1.1.1",
        "react-native": "^0.63.2",
        "react-pouchdb": "^2.0.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
      },
      "build": {
        "appId": "com.Posifier.app",
        "files": [
          "build/**/*",
          "node_modules/**/*"
        ],
        "directories": {
          "buildResources": "assets"
        }
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nf start -p 3000",
        "electron-start": "node src/wait-for-react",
        "electron-pack": "build --em.main=build/electron.js",
        "preelectron-pack": "yarn build",
        "react-start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "electron": "electron .",
        "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
        "dist": "electron-builder",
        "new":"react-scripts build && electron-builder --publish=always"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^11.1.1",
        "electron-builder": "^22.9.1",
        "foreman": "^3.0.1"
      },
      "main": "public/electron.js"
    }
```